# Replacing NaN values in a DataFrame row with values from other rows based on a (non-unique) column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame similar to the following where I have a column with a non-unique value (in this case address) as well as some other columns containing information about it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address': {0:'11 Star Street', 1:'22 Milky Way', 2:'88 Dark Drive', 3:'33 Planet Place', 4:'22 Milky Way', 5:'22 Milky Way'}, 'val': {0:10, 1:'', 2:'', 3:20, 4: 20, 5:''}, 'val2': {0:20, 1:'', 2:'', 3:40, 4:10, 5:''}})

           address val val2
0   11 Star Street  10   20
1     22 Milky Way         
2    88 Dark Drive         
3  33 Planet Place  20   40
4     22 Milky Way  20   10
5     22 Milky Way
```

Some of the addresses appear more than once in the DataFrame and some of those repeated ones are missing information. If a certain row is missing the values, but that address appears in another row in the DataFrame, I'd like to replace the NaN values with those from the same address to get something like this:

```
           address val val2
0   11 Star Street  10   20
1     22 Milky Way  20   10
2    88 Dark Drive         
3  33 Planet Place  20   40
4     22 Milky Way  20   10
5     22 Milky Way  20   10
```

Using something like a dictionary would be infeasible since the DataFrame contains thousands of different addresses.

EDIT: It's safe to assume that either both values are missing or both are present. In other words, there will never be a row with only val and not val2 or vice-versa. However, an answer that could take that possible circumstance into account would be even better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number of ways you can do this, the most easiest is groupby and ffill / bfill the groups.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = df.replace('',np.nan,regex=True).groupby('address').apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())

print(df)

           address   val  val2
0   11 Star Street  10.0  20.0
1     22 Milky Way  20.0  10.0
2    88 Dark Drive   NaN   NaN
3  33 Planet Place  20.0  40.0
4     22 Milky Way  20.0  10.0
5     22 Milky Way  20.0  10.0
```

Another, and more performant method would be using `update` along your axis.

```
vals = df.replace('',np.nan,regex=True).groupby('address').first()

print(vals)
    
                     val  val2
    address                    
    11 Star Street   10.0  20.0
    22 Milky Way     20.0  10.0
    33 Planet Place  20.0  40.0
    88 Dark Drive     NaN   NaN

df = df.set_index('address')

df.update(vals)

                val val2
address                 
11 Star Street   10   20
22 Milky Way     20   10
88 Dark Drive           
33 Planet Place  20   40
22 Milky Way     20   10
22 Milky Way     20   10
```

Comment: Great solution, is there a way to use groupby and fill bfill on only val and val2? For instance, if I had other columns in the DataFrame that may have NaNs but I don't want to overwrite.

Comment: @shaye059, yes, you can conditionally select your columns i.e `vals = df.replace('',np.nan,regex=True).groupby('address')[['val','val2']].first()` then `df.set_index('address')`;`df.update(vals)`  or `df.replace('',np.nan,regex=True).groupby('address')[['val','val2']].apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
`